# How does vitamin C increase iron uptake?

Tags: human-physiology, pathophysiology

I've read that vitamin C increases the iron uptake in the human body. How does that work, physiologically?

Answer (score 5):

Vitamin C both enhances iron uptake, and affects iron metabolism:

> in addition to the known ability of dietary ascorbate to enhance nonheme iron absorption in the gut, ascorbate within mammalian systems can regulate cellular iron uptake and metabolism. Ascorbate modulates iron metabolism by stimulating ferritin synthesis, inhibiting lysosomal ferritin degradation, and decreasing cellular iron efflux. ... Importantly, this iron-uptake pathway is of particular relevance to astrocyte brain iron metabolism and tissue iron loading in disorders such as hereditary hemochromatosis and β-thalassemia. Recent evidence also indicates that ascorbate is a novel modulator of the classical transferrin-iron uptake pathway, which provides almost all iron for cellular demands and erythropoiesis under physiological conditions.

--[The active role of vitamin C in mammalian iron metabolism: much more than just enhanced iron absorption!](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0891584914003220)

Comment: *stimulating ferritin synthesis, inhibiting lysosomal ferritin degradation, and decreasing cellular iron efflux.* Is it possible to translate these 3 things into simpler language?

Comment: Just v various ways of increasing iron metabolism: Making more of the handling proteins, preventing them from being broken down, and keeping iron in the cell